# How can I control conversion from custom object to numpy.longdouble?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a custom class that (for historical reasons) stores high-precision numbers as two integers representing the integer part and the nano-precision non-integer part, e.g.:

```python
class Custom(object):
    def __init__(self, int_, nano_):
        self._int = int_
        self._nano = nano_

    def __float__(self):
        return self._int + self._nano * 1e-9

    def __int__(self):
        return self._int
```

However, when I try to convert this to `numpy.longdouble` it's going through the `__float__` method:

```python
>>> a = Custom(1234567890, 123456789)
>>> print(numpy.longdouble(a))
1234567890.1234567165
>>> print(numpy.longdouble(float(a)))
1234567890.1234567165
>>> print(numpy.longdouble(a._int) + numpy.longdouble(a._nano * 1e-9))
1234567890.123456789
```

The final example there is the result I want. So the question is, how can I override the default behaviour of casting to `numpy.longdouble`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is workable for now as the intermediate `float` cast is unavoidable (see [this issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9968) for details). While `float` type cannot preserve the precision of such a long-digit decimal (check [the `float` representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) for details).

One way to work around is "override" the `numpy.longdouble` function:

```
class Custom(object):
    def __init__(self, int_, nano_):
        self._int = int_
        self._nano = nano_

    def __float__(self):
        return self._int + self._nano * 1e-9

    def longdouble(self):
        return numpy.longdouble(a._int) + numpy.longdouble(a._nano * 1e-9)

    def __int__(self):
        return self._int

a = Custom(1234567890, 123456789)
print(a.longdouble())
```